# Как определить какой был нажат элемент View?

Tags: java, android, setonclicklistener

Попробую объяснить.
Значит добавляю с помощью `inflater` картинки на экран.
Добавил обработчик нажатия, но не могу понять, как определить какой элемент был нажат, чтобы каждому элементу создать определенное действие?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
private void loadNextFlag() {
    /////////////////
    mInt=0;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // цикл выводит два LinearLayout
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++){
        LinearLayout linLayout = getTableRow(row);
        // Место Кнопки
        // в каждый LinearLayout добавляю три картинки
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
            ///////////
            // макет для каждой картинки
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, linLayout, false);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            // вставляю картинку из массива по индексу mInt
            mImageView.setImageResource(persons.get(mInt).getPhotoId());
            linLayout.addView(view);
            // обработчик нажатие
            view.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
            mInt=mInt+1;
        } 
    } 
}


    // нажатие
private View.OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

};
```

Comment: А зачем так извращаться? Почему бы не использовать `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Да пробовал использовать адаптар, но код получиться слишком громоздкий и сложный, много чего еще нужно будет добавить в приложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почему не используете gridview или recyclerview?

// обработчик нажатия

```
   view.setTag(mInt); // для уникальности
   view.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
```

примерно такой обработчик нажатия

```
private View.OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      Toast.makeText(context, "position " + v.getTag(), Length.SHORT).show();

};
```

Comment: про getTag читал, но пока не могу разобраться как ими пользоваться, doAction я так понял это какой-то метод?

Comment: setTag(int i) используется для маркировки елементов. важный момент - для ваших карт все значения должны быть разные. далее в обработчике клика мы получаем етот тег и по нему ориентируемось что за елемент был нажат. 
p.s. совет: лучше использовать gridview для таких действий

Comment: Ну что-то не могу догнать. Например я выбрал даму, как сделать чтобы появилась например надпись Дама?

Comment: немного поправил свой ответ. думаю далее все станет понятно

Comment: Спасибо Бро. Я адаптером сейчас пробую реализовать задуманное.

Comment: будут вопросы, пиши